# NSDateComponents - set weekday components

Tags: objective-c, xcode, date, time, nsdate

I am trying to check if a 2 dates and times are in-between the current time. I have made this function to do so. Here is the function

```
-(BOOL)getStartHour:(NSInteger)startHour getStartMin:(NSInteger)startMin getEndHour:

(NSInteger)endHour getEndMin:(NSInteger)endMin {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *startOfToday;
    [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfToday interval:NULL forDate:now];


    NSDateComponents *startComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    startComps.weekday = 1;
    startComps.hour = startHour;
    startComps.minute = startMin;
//
    NSDateComponents *endComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    endComps.hour = endHour;
    endComps.minute = endMin;
    endComps.weekday = 3;

    NSDate *startDate =  [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:startComps toDate:startOfToday options:0];
    NSDate *endDate =  [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:endComps toDate:startOfToday options:0];
    NSLog(@"%d", [startComps weekday]);
//    NSLog(@"%@", startDate);
//    NSLog(@"%@", now);

    if ([startDate timeIntervalSince1970] < [now timeIntervalSince1970] && [now timeIntervalSince1970]  < [endDate timeIntervalSince1970]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else return NO;
}
```

When I log [startComps weekday] it logs, 0. But today is Tuesday which makes no sense to me. I want to check if this date is between Monday and Wednesday day which I would guess as 1 - 3 or 0 - 2. But why is it logging today (Tuesday) as 0?

In others words I am looking for a dayOfWeek as an integer. SO monday - 1, tuesday 2 and so on

Thakns for the help in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are trying to determine if the current date is between two other dates?  If so why not use `compare:` or some simple maths on the time interval?

Comment: @Droppy yes so I am comparing a lot (like 50) of dates/ times for example I want to know if its monday (day 1) or tuesday (day 2) and it is between 7am and 6pm

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to add weekdays in dateByAddingComponents.  You should be adding plain old days.  And if you read the spec, `weekday` starts with 1 a Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([startDate timeIntervalSince1970] < [now timeIntervalSince1970] && [now timeIntervalSince1970]  < [endDate timeIntervalSince1970]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else return NO;
```

And then return it day by day,

so add in the if statement

```
if weekday < day and day < weekend 
return yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it: you cannot add "Tuesday" to a date "now". What would that mean? Next Tuesday? last Tuesday? or if now is Tuesday is adding Tuesday resulting in Thursday for regions where Tuesday is the second day of the week, or Friday where it is the third day?

So it logs 0 as actually 0 stands for nothing in this case. 1 is Sunday, 2 Monday … 6 Saturday.

Answer (score -1):

```
+(BOOL)isDate:(NSDate*)date betweenStartDate:(NSDate*)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate*)endDate {     
    if (( ([startDate compare:date] == NSOrderedAscending || [startDate compare:date] == NSOrderedSame) ) && ([endDate compare:date] == NSOrderedDescending || [endDate compare:date] == NSOrderedSame)) { 
        return YES;     
    }     
    return NO; 
}
```